# I am hearing weird binary communication sounds through my headset, why?

Tags: sound, bug-reporting

So same headset same cables same laptop, in windows never done this.

Under ubuntu 20.04 lts (when something happens e.g a apt upgrade etc) I faintly hear some binary sounds like two chips are "talking" e.g like the dial up but the distorted sounding part after the middle not the harmonic bell sounds at the beginning.

Just to clarify I am not hearing specifically the 2nd half part of the dial up sound I just used that sound to give you an idea about what kinda sound I am talking about, the actual sounds are different but on the same "category" of sounds if that makes sense.

It cant be RF caused by the cable or anything cause as I said the exact same cable and headset used when booted in windows never does this.

The sound is ver low volume like I have to close any other sound sources in the laptop and on the room (e.g tv) to be able to clearly hear it but its there..

The sound (when it is audible because its not playing 24/7 but seems it does so when the CPU or HDD or network is loaded up with some task ) is audible and does not interfere with e.g the audio of a mp3 or youtube video I might be watching while this happen nor does the volume of said youtube video or mp3 or whatever else that plays sounds on the laptop seem to change/interfere with said sound...

What do you think could cause that?

Should I report it as a bug? where?

Comment: I am pretty sure this not happening under windows proves that it is a ubuntu issue like it is happening now that I am talking to you what I just noticed is that using the touchpad some how "modules" it I mean it goes from grrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrr to grrrrrrrrrrrrrrrbrrrrrrrrrrrgrrrrrrrbrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrgrrrrrrrrr if I swipe the mouse pad put my hand up for a split second and then swipe again "grrrr being the "regular" sound it does without me touching anything. I think that is because moving the corsor sends and addition datastream that becomes autible the pad itself isnt conductive

Comment: This is certainly RF leakage from your system into the headset, possibly through its cord.  Perhaps in linux, you have the audio gain set differently or the mic is also turned on (and passing the audio through).  What's uncertain here is the path that leaks it into your headset.

Comment: Listen I have this laptop for 2 years and use it in the same room and everything is the same  there is not significant gain difference (and even at full blast this doesnt happen) between linux and windows and the laptop does NOT do that in windows, only when I boot to ubutnu it does that there is no way for the interference to be so selective to decide to "hit" my laptop just the few minutes I boot it in ubuntu and then for hours the entire day on windows do nothing and that for weeks on end...even if it is interference it is caused by some ubuntu firmware overloading caps or amps or what not

Comment: also even when on ubuntu the"interference" doesnt become audible unless the computer is using resources (So an other indicator that the sound has to do with chips processing stuff/bit streams going from place to place) if I do nothing on the computer even on ubuntu I dont hear nothing and even IF I use the computer in ubuntu its not a given that the sounds will come up, nor does my position or the laptops position play a role it can be in thesame position and I running something and nothing is audible but then something else starts(e.g automatic update)& the laptop hasnt move but sound starts

Comment: Last but not least this laptop is in an house in a village on a mountain I cant even pick most of the radio stations with my car's radio and barely have  phone signal let alone interference from outside.... and for the 100th time this NEVER has happened for two years now in my at least 3 hours a day usage almost every day but using windows